# MVC query string with ICollection or array

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My MVC 4 web service has a new use case. I need to pass a list of arguments on the query string to a Web API, e.g.,

```
http://host/SomeWebApi?arg=x&arg=y
```

I previously did this simply and easily in my Web Site controller using `ICollection<string> arg` as a parameter in the controller. That is working now, but it is a Web page, as opposed to an API.

Now I am knocking my head against the wall trying to get a Web API version of the same thing to work. I've made a simple test interface, below, and the collection arg is always null. I've tried `List<string>` and `string[]` as types as well. What am I overlooking?

Route register:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "Experiment",
    routeTemplate: "Args",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Storage",
        action = "GetArgTest",
        suite = UrlParameter.Optional,
    },
    constraints: new
    {
        httpMethod = new HttpMethodConstraint(new HttpMethod[] { new HttpMethod("GET") })
    }
);
```

Web API controller code:

```
public string GetArgTest(ICollection<string> suite)
{
    if (suite == null)
    {
        return "suite is NULL";
    }
    else
    {
        return "suite is NON-NULL";
    }
}
```

Test query string that results in "suite is NULL":

```
http://localhost:5101/Args?suite=1&suite=2
```

Comment: If I use GetArgTest(string suite), then I get a non-NULL value, but the text says "(Collection)". Super frustrating.

Comment: Sadly, I timed out on this issue, and resorted to:

`List<string> suite = new List<string>();

IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> queryPairs = Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs();
foreach (var pair in queryPairs)
{
    if (pair.Key == "suite")
    {
        suite.Add(pair.Value);
    }
}`

Answer (score 2):

I came across this answer [ApiController Action Failing to parse array from querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18539057/apicontroller-action-failing-to-parse-array-from-querystring) and discovered that to resolve this you need to put in the `FromUriAttribute`. So in your example:

```
public string GetArgTest([FromUri]ICollection<string> suite)
{
}
```

This makes sense I guess, typically with an API controller you'd expect to be doing more POST and PUT requests for which you'd typically include post data rather than a QueryString.