# ApiController Action Failing to parse array from querystring

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

Using Visual Studio 2012.2, MVC4 web application.

I have requests coming to my ApiController like so:

```
http://localhost/api/keys?ids[]=1&ids[]=2&ids[]=3
```

And I was under the impression that the following method should be able to automagically retrieve the values from the ids[] array:

```
public KeysModel Get(int[] ids){...}
```

However, when a request like the one above comes in, the value of the "ids" parameter is null.

I have inspected that HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString has the values for ids, and I could get to them that way, but that makes unit testing harder.

I have also tried using List ids, [FromUri], [FromUri(Name="ids[]")], object ids, and string ids (interesting note... when ids is a string variable, the value within it is "(Collection)"

Comment: Can you try changing your uri to be like this and try to see if it works: `http://localhost/api/keys?ids=1&ids=2&ids=3` and also you should decorate the parameter with a `[FromUri]` attribute as by default Web API considers complex types to be coming from body

Comment: cant change the uri. it is coming from ember this way, and the goal is to not make a custom adapter/serializer, and instead bend to the will of ember.

Comment: Turns out I was failing to use [FromUri] correctly (thought for certain I had... must be a "stared at it too long" issue).

Comment: Don't use `[]` in your querystring, I believe that's a PHP specific idiom.

Comment: Don't use the same key multiple times in your querystring, that's just stupid!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out:

```
public KeysModel Get([FromUri]int[] ids){...}
```

Was the answer after all.

Dunno what I was doing before...